# React Native TextInput multiline bottom

Tags: android, reactjs, textinput

I have one `TextInput` with some predefined text.
The problem is that on Android the text is displayed at the bottom of the text input. I tryed with `textAlignVertical: 'top'` to display it at top position, but without success the strange thing is that on the IOS is working perfectly

**React Native TextInput Multiline**

> **multiline**
>   If true, the text input can be multiple lines. The default value is false. It is important to note that this aligns the text to the top on iOS, and centers it on Android. Use with textAlignVertical set to top for the same behavior in both platforms.

**current behaviour**:
the text is displayed at the bottom

**desired behaviour**:
the text to be displayed at the top

index.js

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={{
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingBottom: 50,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20}}>
      <TextInput
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            textAlignVertical: 'top',
            borderWidth: 1}}
          autoCapitalize={'none'}
          autoCorrect={false}
          value={this.state.textTabs}
          multiline={true}
          onChangeText={(text) => {this.setState({textTabs: text})}}
          underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
          editable={true}
      />
  </View>
);}
```

Thanks in advance

[image]